# Where does Ubuntu 14.04 log SSH access attempts?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, log

Trying to find out why `fail2ban` is not working.

Where does Ubuntu 14.04 log SSH access attempts?

Comment: You could ask rsyslogd which files it logs to: cat /etc/rsyslog.d/* | egrep -v '^#|^$' | egrep -o '/[^ ]+' on your system.

Answer (score 39):

All login attempts are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`

#### Search for brute-force  SSH logins

Run this command:

```
grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | less
```

#### Search for failed connections

Run this command:

```
grep sshd.*Did /var/log/auth.log | less
```

#### UPDATE:

You should try restarting the syslog daemon to see if it starts to log to the correct file.

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Once you have messages going to `the auth.log` it should start working.

Comment: I looked in /var/log/auth.log and the file is empty and nothing is being logged to it...

Comment: check the update

Comment: Ok, just restarted rsyslog.  Then logged out, tried to log in with a few wrong passwords.  Then went ahead and logged in properly.  Still nothing logged to auth.log.

Comment: What do you think I should look at next?

Comment: I noticed that in /var/log the username that I use (my non-root user) is the owner of a lot of these files.  Could that be the problem do you think?

Comment: Yeah, it was definitely the permissions.  Correcting them, based on the proper settings from another server I have corrected the logging to auth.log.  fail2ban still not banning but I will ask another questions If I cant get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

The default log settings for ssh are "INFO".

If you want to have it include login attempts in the log file, you'll need to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change the "LogLevel" from `INFO` to `VERBOSE`.

After that, restart the sshd daemon with

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

After that, the ssh login attempts will be logged into the /var/log/auth.log file.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting clarifications.    I'll look for how to do that next time I put in an answer.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service` for newer versions of Ubuntu.