# On Ubuntu Artful 17, as a priviledged user, how can I get an email (possible nightly) with information about - what GET requests were sent to port

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, logging

On Ubuntu Artful 17, as a priviledged user, how can I
get an email (possible nightly) with information about

- what GET requests were sent to port 80
- who attempted ssh connections to port 22
- after a "regular user" logged in via ssh

  - what shell commands did they execute
  - did they try sudo
  - did they try to read or delete  /home/otherother/* files

Answer (score 2):

About your question:

1. You can check all your received requests to port 80 in your web server logs.

   - In Apache, its logs can be found in the following addresses depending on the GNU Linux distribution and version.

     - `/var/log/apache/access.log`
     - `/var/log/apache2/access.log`
     - `/var/log/httpd/access.log`
2. About checking your SSH logs, please refer to the following links:

   - [How do I keep track of failed SSH log-in attempts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178016/how-do-i-keep-track-of-failed-ssh-log-in-attempts)
   - [Where does Ubuntu 14.04 log SSH access attempts? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640906/where-does-ubuntu-14-04-log-ssh-access-attempts)
3. You can check the ALL commands executed by another user by opening the `.bash_history` file, located in `/home/<username>/.bash_history`, also keep in mind that the user can delete this log file.

Executing `tail /var/log/auth.log | grep <username>` should give you a user's sudo history.

If the user spawned a shell with `sudo -s`, `sudo su`, `sudo sh`, etc, then the commands executed may appear in the history file of the root user, located in `/root/.bash_history`.

If you want a tool built for this purpose, you can check for [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig). It is [packaged in artful and other Ubuntu releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=sysdig).

> Sydig is an open-source, cross-platform, powerful and flexible system
>   monitoring, analysis and troubleshooting tool for Linux. It can be
>   used for system exploration and debugging.

You can execute `sysdig -c spy_users` to display every command that users launch interactively as well as every directory users visit.

Also you can use `spy_port` to show the data exchanged using the given IP port number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow sysdig is veery interesting

Comment: Yeah! It is!! :)