# the SSH file in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04

What's the file in which the SSH logs are located in ubuntu server 22.04?
FOR exp in centos "/var/log/secure"

Comment: /var/log/auth.log ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does Ubuntu 14.04 log SSH access attempts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640906/where-does-ubuntu-14-04-log-ssh-access-attempts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep track of failed SSH log-in attempts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178016/how-do-i-keep-track-of-failed-ssh-log-in-attempts)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for logs that show SSH connections, they are in

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

example:

```
Sep 20 17:39:52 [hostname] sshd[257027]: Accepted publickey for [username] from [ipaddress] port 57504 ssh2: RSA [alphanumeric-string]
Sep 20 17:39:52 [hostname] sshd[257027]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user [username] by (uid=0)
Sep 20 17:39:52 [hostname] sshd[257250]: Received disconnect from [ipaddress]  port 57504:11: disconnected by user
Sep 20 17:39:52 [hostname] sshd[257250]: Disconnected from user [username] [ipaddress]  port 57504
Sep 20 17:39:52 [hostname] sshd[257027]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user [username]
```